# Webpack generates a bundle.min.js file per image

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have a React project with a lot of images and Webpack2 configuration. Whenever I build my project it generates one bundle file per image - which results in about 140 bundle.min.js files:[image]

I've been searching like a fanatic to find out why or if there is a better way to do this (it would be wonderful if i could just have one file for all these - if possible?). Here is my code:

**webpack.config.prod.js**

```
//  PRODUCTION

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const entry = {
    app: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/app.js')
}

const output = {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js',
}

const plugins = [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        mangle: false,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'), // creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'index-template.html',
        inject: true,
    minify: {
      removeComments: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      removeRedundantAttributes: true,
      useShortDoctype: true,
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
      keepClosingSlash: true,
      minifyJS: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyURLs: true,
    }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'bundle',
        filename: '[name].common.js'
    })
]

const config = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: entry,
    output: output,
    devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: "babel-loader"
            },
      {
              test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
              use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: { limit: 10000, name: './images/[name].[ext]' } // Convert images < 10k to base64 strings (all in images folder)
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                  'css-loader',
                  {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                plugins: (loader) => [ require('autoprefixer')() ]
                            }
                        },
                  'sass-loader',
                ]
              })
            }
        ]
  },
    plugins: plugins,
    externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery'
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "magdenmagden",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A webbased art gallery",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "fransBernhard <mimilundberg@fransbernhard.se>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node dev-server.js --history-api-fallback",
    "build": "rimraf dist && NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
    "test": "rimraf jest/__snapshots__ coverage && jest --no-cache --coverage"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx$)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/jest/config/styleTransform.js",
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$": "<rootDir>/jest/config/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".*\\.scss$": "<rootDir>/jest/config/styleTransform.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "backstopjs": "^2.7.5",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.2",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-modal": "^1.7.7",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scrollchor": "^3.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.5.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "screener-storybook": "^0.7.10",
    "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

So effing greatful for any input!

Comment: `filename: '[name].common.js'`  try changing to `filename: 'bundle.common.js`  otherwise it's not really common.  If you want multiple common chunks you use the names options.. `names: ["app", "subPageA"]`

Comment: @Keith I changed to "filename: 'bundle.common.js" but still same issue .. 147 bundles for all images :(

Comment: How big are the images?, because your url-loader is set to a limit of 10000, basically about 9.8k..

Comment: @Keith I saw now that the biggest one is 2,3 MB, but I'm going to change it to way less. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Yes, I would think so.  Do you need to bundle images anyway,. You would normally just place images inside a directory of your website, and reference them.  url-loader is really only meant for small images, like icons,.  useful for components etc.